# View typescript output js files in VS 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, output, explorer

I've installed TypeScript and Web Essential for Visual Studio 2012.

In a new TypeScript Project were created 3 files:

- default.html
- app.css
- app.ts

In all tutorials, VS 2012 automatically create dropdown for app.ts file in explorer, where is hidden app.js file.

Like on the image below:

[image]

But in my case it doesn't happen for "app.ts", and for new TypeScript file "file1.ts":

[image]

What I need to do in settings for VS 2012, to automatically creating and viewing outputed js files?

Comment: If you look in the folder can you see any JavaScript files there that perhaps aren't showing up in the solutions? This will tell us whether it is a compilation problem (i.e. TypeScript isn't compiling your project) or whether it is just a problem with your solution not showing the files.

Comment: TypeScript compiling in JS files, but it does not displaying in my Solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick fix to show the files inside the solution.

If you click the "Show Hidden Files" icon in Solution Explorer you'll see the files appear and you can right-click and select "Add file to solution".

The slight problem here is that they won't be correctly nested against your TypeScript file - they'll appear on their own. You can fix this by editing the project file to show the dependency between the files - I have shown two files that both depend on `app.ts` as an example, you may only need the JavaScript file to depend on the TypeScript file:

```
<Content Include="app.d.ts">
  <DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="app.js">
  <DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Visual Studio extension to do what you need: [File Nesting](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c)

This extension allows you to specify which files are nested under which other files in the Solution Explorer. You can have files nested manually or by defining file name-based nesting rules.

Here is an example screenshot of what you can do with the plugin:

[image: Nesting files with the "File Nesting" Visual Studio extension]

Comment: This is a plugin to nest files into directories. This question, however, is about displaying already existing (correctly nested) files in Visual Studio.